# How can I freeze a row using the ezsheets API for Google Sheets?

Tags: python, spotipy

I have a nifty script in Python that takes an input of a Spotify album URI and then adds it and some info to the bottom of a Google Sheet that tracks what albums I've listened to.

When I run the script, it seems to wipe away the frozen row at the top of the sheet. Is there a way, at the end of the script, to freeze the first row of the sheet?

I've tried using `sheet.frozenRowCount(1)` at the end to freeze the first row, but I get an error.

Here's my code thus far:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

# import os
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import ezsheets

# set varialbes
cid = '{{ my cid }}'
secret = '{{ my secret key }}'
ss = ezsheets.Spreadsheet('{{ my spreadsheet }}')
sheet = ss[0]
num_rows = sheet.rowCount
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(
    client_id=cid, client_secret=secret))

# get album and set variables
album_input_raw = input("What's the album ID? ")
genre = input("What's the genre? ").title()
country = input("What country is the artist from? ").title()
listen_again_raw = input("Will you listen again? ").upper()


if listen_again_raw == "YES" or listen_again_raw == "Y":
    listen_again_answer = "YES"
    love_it_raw = input("Is it a new favorite? ").upper()
    if love_it_raw == "YES" or listen_again_raw == "Y":
        love_it_answer = "YES"
    else:
        love_it_answer = ""
else:
    listen_again_answer = ""

album_input = album_input_raw[-22:]
album_id = f"spotify:album:{album_input}"
album_info = spotify.album(album_id)
album_name = album_info['name']
artist = album_info['artists'][0]['name']
year_raw = album_info['release_date']
year = year_raw[0:4]

# update the spreadsheet
sheet.updateRow(num_rows + 1, [album_name, artist, 'YES',
                               year, genre, '', country, listen_again_answer, love_it_answer])

sheet.frozenRowCount(1)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/scottsmith/Code/Projects/AddAlbumApp/add_album.command", line 45, in <module>
    sheet.frozenRowCount(1)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't great documentation to the ezsheets module as I can tell. But looking at the [source code](https://github.com/asweigart/ezsheets/blob/master/src/ezsheets/__init__.py#L698) we can see there is the following:

```
@frozenRowCount.setter
    def frozenRowCount(self, value):
```

So, in your code, if you want the first row to remain frozen, you can try something like this perhaps:

```
sheet.frozenRowCount(1)
```

Comment: That's what I thought, too, looking in the docs (which are THIN) but I got an error that `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. It had to be `sheet` in the code, not `ss`, because `sheet` is the full file, and `ss` is the actual sheet I'm working with. But why would it be an integer? so weird.

Comment: Whoops, that was a brain fart on my part. I've edited my answer to reflect working on the sheet instead of the entire spreadsheet. Do you get the ```TypeError``` on this call too?

Comment: When I call it on the sheet, I get the `TypeError`.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't make any sense to me. The ```sheet``` variable should hold a ```Sheet``` object and not an integer... Could you provide the exact line the error occurs? Are you somehow overwriting the ```sheet``` variable at any point?

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/scottsmith/Code/Projects/AddAlbumApp/add_album.command", line 45, in <module>
    sheet.frozenRowCount(1)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable```

That's the line where I'm putting `sheet.frozenRowCount(1)`

Comment: Could you post the whole error in an edit to your original question? I need to see if the error is coming directly from that line or from within the ```ezsheets``` module. It's fairly clear that somewhere, either in your code or in ezsheets, ```frozenRowCount()```, the method, is being overwritten with an integer

Comment: OK. Added it to the original.